# Modx is sorting resource ads as strings, not numerically

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

Tried this both ways, the commented code is the original, results are the same both times.

```
/*
$sql = "select * from modx_site_content where context_key = '$context' order by ABS(id) ASC;";

$results = $modx->query($sql);

foreach($results as $result){

    $output[] = '('.$result['id'].') '.$result['pagetitle'].'=='.$result['id'];

}

*/

$criteria = $modx->newQuery('modResource');

$criteria->where(array(
   'context_key' => $context,
));

$criteria->sortby('id','ASC');

$results = $modx->getCollection('modResource',$criteria);

foreach($results as $result){

    $result = $result->toArray();

    $output[] = '('.$result['id'].') '.$result['pagetitle'].'=='.$result['id'];

}
```

the result will be: 100,101,102,103,50,51,52,53 etc. It's sorting them as a string instead of an integer. I checked the database that field is a primary key [and an integer] if you'll note that even in my commented code I tried to explicitly sort it as an integer.

What is happening here & how do I get this to sort correctly?

[i.e 50,51,52,53,100,101,012 etc...]

Comment: Very strange.   You code *should* return the collection sorted numerically by ID.    if you var_dump $output,  is it sorted wrong?      in the data base, id is: int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT

Comment: yes - if I dump the $output array, it is sorted correctly as is the database

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP array is correctly sorted,  there isn't any problem with your MODx or DB.
Either:

1. On the client-side,  when you process the results object, javascript objects are not guarantied to be ordered (*although they are "almost" always are, depends on browsers*), they'd be lexically sorted.    Use array - arrays **do** have guarantied order.  ECMA says so..
2. You have some php sort() happening on the processor later?